# Why do i get open ssl error while cloning git repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

while cloning a remote repository,

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone <<url>>
```

I'm getting following error,

```
remote: counting objects 3122, done 
remote: compressing objects: 100%(1125/1125)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 openssl ssl_read: error:14095126:ssl routines ssl13_read_n:unexpected eof while reading errorno 0
fatal: early eof
fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index pack failed
```

I have already tried

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is a network problem of some sort or a dropped connection from the server.  Look for antivirus, firewall, and proxy problems, as well as unreliable networks.  `http.postBuffer` has no effect on clones, so you should unset it.

Comment: if its a dropped connection from server, theres no way for me to clone it right?

Comment: You can try to clone a single branch with `-b` and then incrementally fetch the rest.  But if the network connection is too flaky for that, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://flyingtomoon.com/2011/04/12/git-push-is-failed-due-to-rpc-failure-result56/

The problem is most likely because your git buffer is too low.

You will need to increase Git’s HTTP buffer by setting the git config var “http.postBuffer” to 524288000.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: This option only has effect if you have a broken HTTP/1.1 implementation that doesn't support chunked transfer encoding correctly, and should only be used if the server or a proxy is broken.  See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httppostBuffer).